# Can moderators stop closing questions?

Tags: discussion

I was 4 minutes away from answering [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'map' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77262578/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-map-and-int), and someone closed it. Now the OP doesn't get an answer.

I accept that you feel the question wasn't good enough, but it was good enough for me to be able to provide an answer.

I feel this concept of closing questions denies people who do understand the question the ability to answer.

Furthermore, how does someone ask for more information and encourage learning for the OP, if the question gets closed?

If the question isn't good enough, then people won't answer it.

Comment: The comments on that question do mention what is unclear about it though? Also they haven't even provided proper sample input so that one can run that code (For example whats the content of that "Grade Average.txt" file? Are those grades really integers, are they not separated by anything and each of them is a single digit?) Do note that even if the OP improves that specific question to be better it is most likely going to end up being a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, and my answer notes that, but My answer does answer the fault shown. Not everything needs to be perfect.

Comment: Here are my thoughts, the question there isn't really useful to future readers compared to more targeted questions the OP could be asking. The first question they should be asking is "How do I split a string based on a separator?" (For reading the grades into a list) This would be a duplicate, next question they should ask is "How do I perform the same operation on every element of a list?" (For dividing each term in the list) this would again be a duplicate. Compare this to the current question asking about a specific error they are getting, which do you feel is better?

Comment: Agreed, but he doesn't know split returns a list, so we have to tell him. And I can't tell him and none of the current comments do.

Comment: I've commented and pointed them to some questions they should read first which would help solve their (multiple) errors / issues. I've also shared some guidance with them on how they can improve their question in case they aren't able to solve their problem with those links. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: You might want to *outline* what you would have answered to show that the question is actually clear enough. Providing general commentary on the OP's code isn’t the point of [so].

Comment: The site is a collection of good searchable/findable Q&A. The post is not a useful contribution to the site. And neither would an answer be. [tour] [help]

Comment: "I accept that you feel the question wasn't good enough, but it was good enough for me to be able to provide an answer." Cool. We **do not care**, because it **is not the purpose of the site** to operate a help desk, but instead to build a reference.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/

Comment: I've taken a look at some of your other answers, and a significant portion of them start off with questions for the OP. If you have to start off your answer with one or even multiple questions, then either 1) the original question is lacking in focus or clarity; or 2) you're just guessing. In both cases you should refrain from answering. This is a Q&A site, not a help desk or support forum.

Comment: Take this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77263556/2029983) as well. YOu start off by stating "I think", implying you are unsure if the answer is correct. You then go on to provide an answer which is basically the same as an answer you lin to; rather than posting an (almost) identical answer use the close/flag as duplicate feature when the question is answered elsewhere. Finally, the term you used for Google is just noise; if you feel the OP didn't perform adequate searching prior to asking, you could choose to downvote the question (as one of the reasons is for lack of research effort).

Comment: This is pretty much a meta trend at this point. Going in with full accusations ready and not showing any hint that the OP considers the possibility that they may be mistaken themselves.

Comment: I may have missed something but I thought the point of the first comment by @deceze was that the error message the OP claimed occurred could not possibly have been generated by the OPs code. `list(map(...))` will return a `list` if successful, or an entirely different exception will be raised if not. That is why it must be closed as needing more details, namely a minimal reproducible example. I'd love to see how you figured out the error.

Comment: Usage note: You look to be approaching an answer ban (The number of poorly-received answers greatly exceed well-received answers) due to your misunderstanding the goals of the site. An answer ban is exceedingly hard to recover from. They never time out and, unlike a question ban, you don't get rate-limited opportunities to attempt to recover. All you can do is improve the answers, and if the answers are to poorly-conceived questions, it is unlikely that they will attract eyes and upvotes no matter how much improved your answers are.

Comment: Pick the next questions you answer very carefully.

Comment: The question is missing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Clear input, output, runnable code, etc. Sure, the code causing the crash is clearly wrong, but it's not clear what OP's expected output should be so it'd require a guess to answer. I don't see an issue with the closure.

Answer (score 18):

> how does someone ask for more information

By commenting on the question, closed question can still receive comments.

> encourage learning for the OP

Closed question will automatically get a link detailing on how to improve the question, which in turn would help OP to learn & research.

> If the question isn't good enough, then people won't answer it.

Yes? That's the point of QA sites.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255567/discussion-on-answer-by-martheen-can-moderators-stop-closing-questions); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.